# Rails query on multiple primary keys with conditions on association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way in Active Record to construct a single query that will do a conditional join for multiple primary keys?

Say I have the following models:

```
Class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
end

Class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :athlete
  named_scope :run, :conditions => {:type => "run"}
  named_scope :best, :order => "time", :limit => 1
end
```

With that, I could generate a query to get the best run time for an athlete:

```
  Athlete.find(1).workouts.run.best
```

How can I get the best run time for each athlete in a group, using a single query?

The following does not work, because it applies the named scopes just once to the whole array, returning the single best time for all athletes:

```
Athlete.find([1,2,3]).workouts.run.best
```

The following works.  However, it is not scalable for larger numbers of Athletes, since it generates a separate query for each Athlete:

```
[1,2,3].collect {|id| Athlete.find(id).workouts.run.best}
```

Is there a way to generate a **single query** using the Active Record query interface and associations?

If not, can anyone suggest a SQL query pattern that I can use for find_by_SQL?  I must confess I am not very strong at SQL, but if someone will point me in the right direction I can probably figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Workout objects with the best time:

```
athlete_ids = [1,2,3]
# Sanitize the SQL as we need to substitute the bind variable
# this query will give duplicates
join_sql    = Workout.send(:santize_sql, [ 
    "JOIN (
      SELECT a.athlete_id, max(a.time) time 
      FROM   workouts a
      WHERE  a.athlete_id IN (?)
      GROUP BY a.athlete_id
    ) b ON b.athlete_id = workouts.athlete_id AND b.time = workouts.time", 
    athlete_ids])


Workout.all(:joins => join_sql, :conditions => {:athlete_id => })
```

If you require just the best workout time per user then:

```
Athlete.max("workouts.time", :include => :workouts, :group => "athletes.id", 
 :conditions => {:athlete_id => [1,2,3]}))
```

This will return a OrderedHash

```
{1 => 300, 2 => 60, 3 => 120}
```

**Edit 1**

The solution below avoids returning multiple workouts with same best time. This solution is very efficient if `athlete_id` and `time` columns are indexed.

```
Workout.all(:joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN workouts a 
  ON workouts.athlete_id  = a.athlete_id AND 
     (workouts.time < b.time OR workouts.id < b.id)",
  :conditions => ["workouts.athlete_id = ? AND b.id IS NULL", athlete_ids]
)
```

Read this [article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/) to understand how this query works. Last check (`workouts.id < b.id`) in the `JOIN` ensures only one row is returned when there are more than one matches for the best time. When there are more than one match to the best time for an athlete, the workout with the highest id is returned(i.e. the last workout).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting a SQL syntax error for the full object query.  However, I think you have pointed me in the right direction with the GROUP BY clause.  I will take this opportunity to get smarter on complex sequel joins using GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: Nice, that did the trick, thanks.  The syntax error was helpful though, as it forced me to go through a few mySQL tutorials.  Time for me to stop blindly relying on rails and get smart on the underlying db queries.

Comment: One question on the full query.  Say I have a large number of workouts and athletes.  Would the query be more efficient with the athlete_id condition on the right table (full Workout objects), inside the left table (eg as a WHERE condition of the SELECT), or on both?

Comment: Updated by answer, take a look.

Comment: Very nice, thanks.  The same pattern is proving useful for optimizing several other query problems I have.

Comment: Sorry, one more question.  Joining on athlete_id and time may return more than one row.  There may be several workouts with the same athlete and time, but different in other attributes.  I can add those to the WHERE clause for the SELECT.  But how do I get a unique JOIN?  I am trying to JOIN off the workout.id, but that does not work.  Any idea why?

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: Thanks, excellent resource.  I would have never arrived at this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly following will not work

```
Athlete.find([1,2,3]).workouts.run.best
```

Because Athlete.find([1,2,3]) returns an array and you can't call Array.workouts

You can try something like this:

```
 Workout.find(:first, :joins => [:athlete], :conditions => "athletes.id IN (1,2,3)", :order => 'workouts.time DESC')
```

You can edit the conditions according to your need.

Comment: You are right, I got sloppy in my pseudo-code.  I actually created another named scope for Workout, called by, with a lambda condition to receive an array of athlete_id's.  Then I could call Workout.all.by([1,2,3]).run.best.  But that did not work, returning only the best time for all athletes, not the best time for each athlete.

Comment: According to my testing, your suggestion does the same thing: returns the single best time for all athletes, rather than a separate best time for each athlete.  The help is much appreciated, though.